# Set Variable with parsed JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a parsed JSON which looks like this

```
{
    "pageName":"dsfdsf:sdfdsf:home",
    "prop1":"dsf:dsf","prop46":"OD",
    "prop5":"/content/",
    "prop24":"A Taste Of Home",
    "prop6":"1c4074ca-89bf-4d9f-8bd2-a5dc5f3ecf74",
    "prop3":"Home",
    "prop70":"dsf",
    "prop4":"dsf",
    "prop71":"desktop",
    "prop10":["dsfdsf"],
    "prop11":["sdfdsf"],
    "channel":"dsf"
}
```

I am able to extract the key and value from this. I want to then set this map as JS variables in my script tag like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     s.channel ="dsf"  // i need the prefix to be s. always and the variable should be set as s.key=value;
</script>
```

When i do `s.key=value` nothing happens. I have tried defining `s` as `JS` object as well but without joy. I want to pass these values to Tracking server so the variable name needs to be `s`.

The below works

```
if(key==="channel"){
s.channel = value // this works
```

but `s.key=value` doesn't.

Comment: It should be `s[key] = value` if you don't want to use `key` as a literal property name.

Comment: Thanks a ton it worked. Never thought it would be that. Please post it as answer and i will upvote.

Comment: I can't post an answer, I closed the question as a duplicate.